# (Cake)PHP Error Thrown in Nested Function Doesn't Get Back to Initial Function

Tags: php, error-handling, cakephp-2.3

This isn't necessarily a CakePHP problem but I'm using CakePHP 2.8 and PHP 5.6.

I have a function named save_order which calls another function named `changePathItemOrder` using a try/catch. That function calls another function named `_reorderItemsOnPath`, which in turn calls another function named `_moveItemsForwards`.  It's a few levels deep, so here's a little graphic to keep us all on track:

[Cascade of Functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x2Ss.png)

The try/catch in sort_order is:

```
$data['status'] = 'success';
try {
    $this->PathRepository->deletePathItemFromPath($milestoneId, $pathId, $accountId);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    debug('Caught error');
    $data['status'] = 'error';
    $data['message'] = $e->getMessage();
}
$this->set(compact('data'));
$this->render('/Elements/json');
```

If an error occurs in `_moveItemsForwards`, I throw an error like:

```
throw new InternalErrorException('Invalid path item ID: ' . $pathItemId);
```

The problem is that the try/catch in sort_order doesn't catch the error thrown by `_moveItemsForwards`. The catch doesn't even execute because the debug doesn't show up in the resulting error message. I just get the following Error :-

```
500 Error! Something broke!
Return to the homepage
Invalid path item ID: 76
```

What's the best way to handle this error and get the error message back to the save_order function?

Comment: Are you sure the exception is happening inside the try block? Maybe something else is happening and a fatal error is being throw. Try catching a Throwable instead of a Exception.

Comment: Do you have the correct `use`s in place? You're catching `Exception` without any namespace in the code shown. You either need `catch \Exception` here or else `use \Exception` earlier on.

Comment: Did you try to add a `throw new Exception('stopping here');` just after the `try` line ?